Symfony, API Platform, JWT: JWT Token not found (401)
I am trying to protect my API with JWT. But the problem is, that I am not able to access Swagger UI, because I get 401: JWT Token not found.
packages/api_platform.yml
api_platform:
    swagger:
        api_keys:
            JWT:
                name: Authorization
                type: header

packages/security.yml
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            jwt: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }


when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon

lexik_jwt_authentication.yml
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'

    api_platform:
        check_path: /api/login_check
        username_path: email
        password_path: security.credentials.password

As well I generated JWT with lexik:jwt:generate-keypair. As soon as I create CURL Request from terminal, I get the Token back
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://project-symfony.ddev.site/index.php/api/login_check -d '{"username":"admin@admin.com","password":"admin"}'

I'm trying to use Swagger UI and add a bearer token there. But when I go to https://project-symfony.ddev.site/api, it says 'JWT is not found.' Any ideas? I've checked tutorials from API Platform, Lexik Documentation, Symfony, but nothing's working. I am Using Symfony 6.4.4, with security-bundle

I have modified API's Pattern in the security.yml by adding a slash at pattern: ^/api/
Complete security.yml
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api/  #Slash added 
            stateless: true
            jwt: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon


With this change, API Platform/Swagger UI works seamlessly, allowing authorizations to be processed by entering the bearer token.
